# jQuery. Why are none of my css class values present when I assign a css class?

Tags: jquery, css

I create and append a `div` with an id`:`

```
classyDiv = document.createElement('div');
classyDiv.setAttribute('id', 'classyDivID');

parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDivID');
parentDiv.appendChild(classyDiv);
```

I now want to attach this css class to the child div:

```
.igv-top-left-width {
    position: absolute;
    top: 128px;
    left: 256px;
    width: 512px;

}
```

I use jQuery to assign the css class:

```
$('#classyDivID').addClass('.igv-top-left-width');
console.log($('#classyDivID').css('left'));
```

When I echo the css class values I get complete nonsense values. For `left` I get `auto`. Huh? Whah?. As if I am referring to some other random css class. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the period. `addClass` expects a class name, not a selector. What you're currently doing is equivalent to `<div class=".class-name">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change:

```
$('#classyDivID').addClass('.igv-top-left-width');
```

to:

```
$('#classyDivID').addClass('igv-top-left-width');
```

You don't need the `.` to add the class here

Comment: No joy. var cssClassName="igvTopLeftWidth"; $('#classyDivID').addClass(cssClassName); and console.log("top") echos the word auto. console.log("width") echos 1184px. Sigh.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to replicate your problem?

Comment: Got it, it works fine. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dugla/74eeC/. The problem had to do with the fact I was running inside a unit test (jQuery QUnit). I'll give this one to you Felix for the suggestion. Cheers.